# Trouble trying to populate a dropdown menu with a json array returned by php

Tags: php, json, ajax

When I am trying to populate my dropdown menu with `ajax` I am not able to get the desired values into the dropdown menu.

Could you tell me where the mistake is? The `accno` returned from `php` is `json` array to be filled in the drop down menu.

```
function showACC(str) 
{
    if (str == "") 
    {
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 

        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
                var doc = window.document.createElement("doc");
                var myarray = JSON.parse($source);

                var dropdown = document.getElementById("DropdownList");

                for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {


                    dropdown[dropdown.length] = new Option(myArray[i], myArray[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","data.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}}
```

---

```
<?php

/*
   Connecting to the database
*/
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'neel';
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'library';
mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());

/*
  Executing SQL query
*/
$queryResult = mysql_query('SELECT acc_no  FROM lib_iss_ret where stu_id="07751a1035"') or die(mysql_error());
$source = array();

/*
  Building the source string
*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult)) {
  array_push($source, $row['acc_no']);
}

/*
  Printing the source string
*/
echo json_encode($source);

?>
```

Comment: `var myarray = JSON.parse($source);` What is `$source`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that, I suppose, you think that php variable `$source` is available in your javascript with the same name. This is a mistake. PHP knows nothing about javascript.

Response from server comes as a `responseText` property of `xmlhttp` object. So you should parse `xmlhttp.responseText` instead of `$source`:

```
var myarray = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

To check what you get you could use `alert` or `console.log` with developers console.